# My friend's next country

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, geography

My friend gave me this puzzle.

Here is the list of the places I went to, in this particular order, and their scores.

- United States (USA)  1890.19
- Soviet Union (URS)   860.14
- France (FRA) 749.02
- Germany (GER)    711.78
- Great Britain (GBR)  702.79
- Italy (ITA)  581.72
- Sweden (SWE) 575.41
- Canada (CAN) 501.07
- Norway (NOR) 479.38
- Finland (FIN)    456.21
- Russia (RUS) 451.77
- Australia (AUS)  426.19
- Japan (JPN)  425.06
- China (CHN)  419.67
- East Germany (GDR)   399.83
- Hungary (HUN)    383.53
- Netherlands (NED)    373.65
- Austria (AUT)    366.18
- Switzerland (SUI)    321.18
- Poland (POL) 308.47
- Romania (ROU)    267.78
- South Korea (KOR)    249.63
- West Germany (FRG)   220.35
- Bulgaria (BUL)   188.05
- Cuba (CUB)   175.16
- Denmark (DEN)    166
- Czechoslovakia (TCH) 148.24
- Brazil (BRA) 133.8
- Ukraine (UKR)    131.07
- Belgium (BEL)    131.03
- Spain (ESP)  104.73
- New Zealand (NZL)    100.62
- Germany (EUA)    100.4
- Belarus (BLR)    100.38
- Unified Team (EUN)   92.57
- Greece (GRE) 89.26
- Czech Republic (CZE) 88.27
- Kenya (KEN)  76.22
- Yugoslavia (YUG) 72.66
- Kazakhstan (KAZ) 71.43
- Mexico (MEX) 69.06
- South Africa (RSA)   64.72
- Turkey (TUR) 61.58
- Argentina (ARG)  61.42
- Iran (IRI)   58.62
- Slovenia (SLO)   53.26
- North Korea (PRK)    50.82
- Azerbaijan (AZE) 50.34
- Jamaica (JAM)    49.44
- Ethiopia (ETH)   44.64
- Estonia (EST)    37.7
- ???????? (???) ??.??

What is the final place I'm going to, and what is its associated score?

## Hints

It's been a week, I'm adding a hint:

> My friend once told me: Pffff, the mosquitoes, the hotness, I hate summer. Look at winter, it's way better, perfect temperature, cool TV programs, wonderful snow on mountains, delicious raclette...

Comment: Both Soviet Union *and* some of its constituent now-countries are in the list ... interesting.

Comment: Does the amount of ? relate to the amount of letters and numbers?

Comment: @tyui yes, it does!

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but perhaps a point in the right direction.

> Given the number of entries that correspond to ex-countries, such as East Germany/West Germany/Germany, TCH/CZE, the first thing that comes to mind is that it is related to the Olympic Games. What’s more, the rank corresponds ‘approximately’ to the ranking of overall medal tally for combined Olympic Games. But the are a two main issues with this:
>
> 1.  There are a couple of major outliers. As examples, China is much lower down the list than it should be and Canada is much higher up the list than it should be. 
>
> 2. I have no idea how the score is derived. It’s not a ratio of total medal numbers vs. disqualified medals or per capita.